# Ruby method/algorithm for permutations with empty values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm

I have 3 lists: headlines, sub-headlines, and image_urls.

Each list is an array, and each may contain 0 or more items.

I want to create a permutation of every combination in this format:

```
[
  {headline: X1, subheadline: Y1, image_url: Z1}
  {headline: X1, subheadline: Y2, image_url: Z1}
  {headline: X1, subheadline: Y3, image_url: Z1}
  {headline: X1, subheadline: Y1, image_url: Z2} 
  ...
]
```

The only thing is, for any missing items I want it to be an empty string `''`.

The "dumb" solution I first had was to do...

```
headlines.each do |headline|
  subheadlines.each do |subheadline|
    image_urls.each do |url|
      {headline: headline, subheadline: subheadline, image_url: url}
    end
  end
end
```

But the only problem is, if one of the inner arrays is empty, say `subheadline`, instead of appending blank and continuing to iterate it will just stop right there, and all permutations will not be processed.

What method or approach might help me here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before start you could

```
headlines << '' if headlines.empty?
subheadlines << '' if subheadlines.empty?
image_urls << '' if image_urls.empty?
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a little function:

```
def maybe_add_empty_string_to_arr(arr)
  if arr == []
    [""]
  else
    arr
  end
end
```

Then call your loop with:

```
maybe_add_empty_string_to_arr(headlines).each do |headline|
  maybe_add_empty_string_to_arr(subheadlines).each do |subheadline|
  ...
```

Comment: I chose the other answer because it's more efficient, although I came to this realization exactly as I posted the question :)